# Rails mysql fetching old values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, delayed-job

We are trying to implement sharding for our production environment. The problem we are facing is we have delayed jobs which is taking care of some background processing. If we update a model and put an entry in our delayed job for procession in delayed job it is fetching the older values of that object and it is not consistent. For example User model has name, position if i want to trigger a mail whenever he changes the position so it is like

```
usr = User.find(1)
usr.position = "foo"
usr.save
```

In delayed job if i fetch usr = User.find(1) it is fetching the old values. We use passenger in our production environment, mysql we are still on Rails 2.3.18. Before we faced the same problem in our App actions also which caused by a bug in mysql query cache which we stopped using it and the problem is solved in our app actions

Comment: Is the problem at DB level or at Rails level? I mean: if you do the query by hand on the DB, do you get the right answer or not?

Comment: Yes i get the right value if i directly query from the DB console (same query which i get from rails logger )and also if i run the same job again it is unable to fetch ..

Comment: keeping this ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset! just before load in perform for delayed job fixed the issue .. i am not sure why it is causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to nail down the problem it is to do with repeatable read by mysql more info on 
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/

In our delayed jobs we are saving the object which has after_commit callbacks. Which is leaving a transaction open (because it is invalid) and  which is neither committing or issuing a rollback. I checked the after_commit code where they will disable the rollback and they do only if there is an exception in my case it is simply returning false without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This looks lika a cache problem, there are many workarounds, before you move on and invalidate the whole cache, which has a performance impact, I reccomend you issue a `usr.reload` before you use the object.

Regards,

Comment: Idavod sometimes we are triggering some delayed jobs from object creation also even there it is not fetching the saved object at all.In this case i can't use reload as i will get an error in find itself. I wrote a new reset method 
 `def reset_with_change_user!
          if @connection.respond_to?(:change_user) 
                      @connection.change_user(@config[:username], @config[:password], @config[:database])
                   end
        end`
where i removed the configure connection actually which basically set the utf-8 and SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0 which worked fine.